# Suitescript UserEvent submitField

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I had trying an condition if create date from **item fullfilment**, than  date at Sales Order changes according to date in itam fullfilmet. I try an scripting and get problem

```
*@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@author test 
 */
    define(['N/record'],
        function(record){
            function beforeSubmit(context){
                var record = context.newRecord;
                var curr = record.getValue({

                    fieldId:'Tranddate'
                    //is field fullfilmet or sales order(?)
                });
            curr.submitField({
                        type: record.Type.salesorder,
                        id: curr.getValue('Tranddate'),
                        values: {
                            trandate: curr.getValue('trandate')
                        },
                options:{
                    enableSourcing: false,
                    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
                }

            });
            }
return{
beforeSubmit:beforeSubmit
            };
        });
```

so i got an error

org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function submitField in object Thu Dec 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

Comment: It's `submitFields` (in plural), and you need to apply it on the record module (`record.submitFields({...})`). https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267283788.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your script should be.

```js
*@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@author test 
 */
    define(['N/record'],
        function(record){
            function beforeSubmit(context){
                var currRec = context.newRecord;
                
            record.submitField({
                        type: record.Type.salesorder,
                        id: currRec.getValue('createdfrom'),
                        values: {
                            trandate: currRec.getValue('trandate')
                        },
                options:{
                    enableSourcing: false,
                    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
                }

            });
            }
return{
beforeSubmit:beforeSubmit
            };
        });
```